# Ubuntu 20.04 no login screen

Tags: login-screen

My Ubuntu machine will not show a login screen when turned on.It’s an known working install.I do get the Ubuntu splash screen on boot but after that the screen just goes black. None of the information I found online seems to help.
I would also like to add that I did not do any software updates before this happened.
Help would be appreciated

Comment: A new install that has never worked or a working install that has stopped working?

Comment: @David It’s a working install that stopped working

Comment: That info needs to be in the question. Please edit the question and add that info.